# Is the dimension of a Noetherian local ring equal to its associated graded ring?

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian, krull-dimension, local-rings, dimension-theory-algebra

For a noetherian local ring $A$ with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, let $I$ be a primary ideal in $A$, the associated graded ring is
$$ \bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty} I^n/I^{n+1}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. First we deal with the case $I=\mathfrak m$.

If we define $f(n)=l(A/\mathfrak{m}^n)$ where $l$ denotes the length of a module,
then for large $n$, $f(n)$ equals a polynomial of degree $d=\dim A$ in $n$.
Replacing $A$ by its associated graded ring with $I=\mathfrak m$
does not change $f(n)$, and so does not change $d$.

Now consider general $I$. Then $\mathfrak{m}\supseteq I\supseteq \mathfrak{m}^r$
for some positive integer $r$. Therefore $g(n)=l(A/I^n)$
satisfies $f(n)\le g(n)\le f(rn)$. Again, $g(n)$ is a polynomial for
large $n$, and these inequalities imply that it has the same degree $d$
as $f(n)$.

If we consider the graded ring $R=\bigoplus(I^n/I^{n+1})$, this
is also a Noetherian local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}'
=\mathfrak{m}/I\oplus (I/I^2)\oplus (I^2/I^3)\oplus\cdots$ and having
$I'=0\oplus (I/I^2)\oplus (I^2/I^3)\oplus\cdots$ as a primary ideal. Then $l(R/I'^n)
=g(n)$ also and $R$ also has dimension $d$.

Comment: There is a problem: in general, m is not the only maximal ideal in the associated ring . I think we should do localization at m on the associated ring, then show that it is the maximal ideal of the maximal chain of prime ideals...